# Exporting jar file in VS Code

Tags: java, jar, visual-studio-code, export

I recently switched over to VS Code from Eclipse as my primary Java editor. I need to frequently export my code into a jar file which includes all libraries and dependencies for running on a Raspberry Pi. However, I currently see no obvious menus or tabs to accomplish this purpose.

Are there any extensions or built-in features which will behave in a manner similar to Eclipse's "Export" window? Would I be able to easily write a script to export for me?

Comment: Huh, I just wonder why you switched to basic text editor for java, maybe you should try intellij or netbrans if eclipse is not for you? But for building a .jar you should use maven or gradle anyway - but IDE can still provide nice tools to use them too.

Comment: Huh, you should try it, then you get the point why VSCode is so popular

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your project has Maven, you can simply call `mvn package` or `mvn clean install` from VS Code's embedded command line.
Reference for Maven: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Tutorial%3A+Build+a+JAR+file+with+Maven+in+5+minutes

For spring users in Windows type: `.\mvnw package`

EDIT: If you get `'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`, you need to: [download](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and [install](https://maven.apache.org/install.html) `mvn`. Install is just setting the PATH env.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to export jar file then you first get maven extension installed in your vscode. In explorer of your vscode, you can find different options as shown in screenshot below.
[image]

In **JAVA PROJECTS** you can find option **export jar**(shown by right arrow). Just click on it and it will automatically create jar file of your project.

Answer (score 3):

I use "pure java" as my projects are simple enough, and the button you are looking for is this one

[magic button screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i8Sk.png)

I only have installed Extension Pack for Java

[only plugin needed screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxdlb.png)

Next steps are pretty intuitive, even the "checkboxes" for including external jars

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your project has app package. Under that a App.java class resides which has the main method.It also uses **yourlib.jar** library. Now after building App.java file from vscode the class files let's assume the class file folder structure is

```
bin
   |app
       |App.class
```

Now go to the bin folder and make a manifest.txt file in bin folder. manifest.txt file must contain Main-Class . here app.App is the name of the Main-Class.Following can be the contents of manifest.txt file

```
 Main-Class: app.App
 Class-Path: yourlib.jar
```

**Note** manifest.txt file must be ended with a new line or carriage return . If your manifest file only contains Main-Class no Class-Path The after `Main-Class: app.App` put a new line at least. Now copy the **yourlib.jar** file in **bin** and run this command from the **bin** folder

```
jar cfmv App.jar manifest.txt app/
```

then test the Jar with

```
java -jar App.jar
```

**Note:** You can run and build class file by installing https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java extension.

Answer (score -3):

You can run Maven Task in VS Code. Reference:

https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-create-debug-java-project-in-visual-studio-code/